# I am not able to send session storage data through AJAX to the server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session-storage

I have stored the ID of the user in session storage. I need to perform an action using the ID so I am passing it to the server using AJAX but the data is not reaching the server.

AJAX:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#coupon_code').hide();
  $('#coupon_status').hide();
  var id = sessionStorage.getItem('user_id');

  $('#generate').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      dataType : 'json',
      url : 'http://127.0.0.1/ionic/generate.php',
      data : id,
      beforeSend : function(){
        console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('user_id'));
        console.log("data sent");
      },
      success : function(data){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.code);
        console.log(data.value);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

PHP script:-

```
<?php
require 'db_connect.php';
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$id = $_POST['id'];

$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$string = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
}
$ins = "INSERT INTO `coupon_code` (id,code,status) VALUES ('$id,'$string',1)";
$res_ins = mysqli_query($con,$ins);

if($res_ins)
{
    echo json_encode(array("status" => "done", "code" => $string,"value" => "1"));
    //echo $string;
}
else
{
    echo "NO";
}
?>
```

EDIT :-
Firebug result
[image]

Comment: Is the post data showing in the network tab?  Also if you do a post using curl using the data in your network tab does it show in your server?

Comment: unless `id` is some query string (eg id=123&va=something), `data : id,` won't send the data properly. `data` needs to be a query string, object, or array of values.

Comment: @Austio I didn't get you

Comment: id is simple number in this case 11

Comment: If you want to catch it with `$_POST['id']` you have to actually send it that way, as `data : {id : id},`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078085/how-to-send-multiple-data-with-ajax-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only sending value in json data - you need to send key-value pair - so through key you will get data at server

This should work for you - also you can debug data in firebug what is going to server or not

You need to replace 
This line `data : id,`

with this line `data : {'id' : id},`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#coupon_code').hide();
      $('#coupon_status').hide();
      var id = sessionStorage.getItem('user_id');

      $('#generate').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          dataType : 'json',
          url : 'http://127.0.0.1/ionic/generate.php',
          data : {'id' : id},
          beforeSend : function(){
            console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('user_id'));
            console.log("data sent");
          },
          success : function(data){
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.code);
            console.log(data.value);
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

There is also a bug in insert query -

```
$ins = "INSERT INTO `coupon_code` (id,code,status) VALUES ('$id,'$string',1)";
```

(')single quote not closed for '$id

```
$ins = "INSERT INTO `coupon_code` (id,code,status) VALUES ('$id','$string',1)";
```

Comment: Nothing happened even after doin this

Comment: Have you checked ajax post request in firebug - there you can see if data is going to server or not -?

Comment: Yes server side code looking ok - you can debug to see what hapning like
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id; 
die;

Comment: I am checking it with firebug now

Comment: I added the firebug response

Comment: As is see in your uploaded firebug data is going successfully to server.. Now you can debug your server code line by line if not working :)

Comment: Ohkay I'll try that now

Comment: There is bug in this line - 
$ins = "INSERT INTO `coupon_code` (id,code,status) VALUES ('$id,'$string',1)";

Update  - 
$ins = "INSERT INTO `coupon_code` (id,code,status) VALUES ('$id','$string',1)";

Comment: Yes you were right Please post your solution as answer

Comment: But the result I got was not in my ajax function but in a simple form. I am not getting the result in my ajax now

Comment: " I am not getting the result in my ajax now' - what do you mean - result not coming as response in firebug?

Comment: Nothing I am sorry. Everything is right now. Thanks a lot