# Posting multiple values to PHP from Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax request to save data from JavaScript and write it to a file using a separate ("saveData.php") PHP file. I want to know if I can "POST" multiple JavaScript variables / strings within the same Ajax request.

For instance, I currently have this:

```
function saveData(){ //sends an AJAX request to saveData.php
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "saveData.php",
    dataType: "text/plain",
    ContentType: "charset=utf-8",
    data: {"data": dataString},
  })
}
```

And this works great via my PHP file, which as this code:

```
$data = $_POST["data"];
$theFile = fopen("Data/" . FileNameHere . ".txt", "a+");

// Save data into a file based on their username
fwrite($theFile, $data);
fclose($theFile);
```

But I want to save the file based on their userID, which is a JavaScript variable.

Can I do something like this:

```
function saveData(){ //sends an AJAX request to saveData.php
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "saveData.php",
    dataType: "text/plain",
    ContentType: "charset=utf-8",
    data: {"data": dataString},
    data1: {"data1": userID},   <-----new line with JS variable 'userID'
  })
}
```

And PHP file like this:

```
// Prepare line of data to save.
$data = $_POST["data"];
$userID = $_POST["data1"];     <--------New code to POST "data1" from Ajax
$theFile = fopen("Data/" . $userID . ".txt", "a+");

// Save data into a file based on their username
fwrite($theFile, $data);
fclose($theFile);
```

Comment: It's JSON. Have a read of https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp (or other tutorial)

Comment: More reading too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078085/how-to-send-multiple-data-with-ajax-jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can, you are passing a JSON Object so it can have as many properties as you like.

Read More about, how to send multiple data in server side [via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085649/ajax-multiple-data). 
Try this

```
function saveData(){ //sends an AJAX request to saveData.php
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "saveData.php",
    dataType: "text/plain",
    ContentType: "charset=utf-8",
    data: {
            "data": dataString, 
            "data2":val2,
            "data3":val3,
            "data4":val4
          },
  })
}
```

And PHP file like this:

```
$data = $_POST["data"];
$userID = $_POST["data2"];
$theFile = fopen("Data/" . $userID . ".txt", "a+");

// Save data into a file based on their username
fwrite($theFile, $data);
fclose($theFile);
```

Comment: I am glad to help you.

Comment: Hope you didn't object to my adding a bit to your answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, I didn't. If you want to add more information feel free to add.

Comment: @Phoenix404 I need a help. I wonder if I can ask for help from you?

Comment: yup sure... go ahead