# How to get a success message in this particular AJAX call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using this particular way of sending the data via Ajax and I am not able to get a success message using this. Is there another way to send multiple data after doing `$('form').serialize()` and also get a success message back. The code that I am using is mentioned below.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#sub').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                method:"POST",
                url:"main_class.php",
                data:$('form').serialize() + "&submit=submit"

            }); 
        });
    });    
    </script>
```

Comment: Why can't you make it as an object and send as data.?

Comment: @Abinthaha You mean something like `data: "{numberId:1,companyId:531}"`? I have got a lot of data and sending in the above format is not viable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use `ajax` `success` and `error` messages.

For example you can use this code snippet:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#sub').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
        dataType:"json",
        method:"POST",
        url:"main_class.php",
        success: function(data) {
            statusMsg = 'Data was succesfully captured';
            $("#successMsg ").text(statusMsg );
        },
        error: function(data) {
            statusMsg  = 'Error';
            $("#statusMsg ").text(statusMsg );
        },
    });

    return false;
</script>
```

Another way to solve your problem. your 
Just collect your data and convert to json and use it in your data field:
: [**Follow the steps from here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25515629/6189974)

Comment: Where is the data?

Comment: just edit and put your data value to ajax`s data row :)

Comment: I just said that I can't use `data: "{numberId:1,companyId:531}"` as I have lots of data in the form it is not viable to send data in that fashion.

Comment: how do you get this data? You can convert this datas to json and after that you can use this json with data field: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25515629/6189974

Comment: Could you plz write it down in the answer. It would be east to follow. Thanks.

Comment: just give a shot and get your solution :)

Comment: Yes, definitely will do that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax success method to get ajax succes response and also use error method whether ajax has error it will catch in error method for example.

```
$.ajax({
      method:"POST",
            url:"main_class.php",
          data:$('form').serialize() + "&submit=submit",
          success:function(data) {
            Console.log(data)
          }, error: function (e){}
       });
```

Comment: It throws an error. `success` construct is not permitted when using data in the above format.

Comment: You can use form object like this.       var form = $('form').serializeArray();
var uniquekey = { // other value you want to put
      name: "uniquekey",
      value: $('#UniqueKey').val()
};
form.push(uniquekey);.      And pass this form to data

Comment: Just tried what you said and it throws an error too. Could you plz guide me through the correct way of doing that?