# How To add another post name/variable inside ajax script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$("#epdate").bind("change", function() {
 $.ajax({
     type: "GET", 
     url: "change6-emp.php",
     data: "epdate="+$("#epdate").val(),
     success: function(html) {
         $("#output").html(html);
     }
 });
});


});
</script>
```

i have this code and i want to add another variable
inside ajax script adding another

> data: "empname="+$("#empname").val(),

dopesnt work i hope someone would help me. thank you
and how can i call a postname or make a postname into session an call it into another php page?

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078085/how-to-send-multiple-data-with-ajax-jquery/10078120

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are multiple ways, either separate them using a `&` character.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$("#epdate").bind("change", function() {
 $.ajax({
     type: "GET", 
     url: "change6-emp.php",
     data: "epdate=" + $("#epdate").val() + "&empname="+$("#empname").val(),
     success: function(html) {
         $("#output").html(html);
     }
 });
});


});
</script>
```

Or alternatively, you can use an object which holds the name-value pair.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$("#epdate").bind("change", function() {
 $.ajax({
     type: "GET", 
     url: "change6-emp.php",
     data: { epdate : $("#epdate").val(), empname : $("#empname").val() },
     success: function(html) {
         $("#output").html(html);
     }
 });
});


});
</script>
```

---

**UPDATE 1:** You can also pass it as an array in the following format,

```
data : [{
    name : 'epdate',
    value : $("#epdate").val()
  }, {
    name : 'empname',
    value : $("#empname").val()
  }],
```

---

**UPDATE 2:** There is build in functions in jQuery to do the same, use [`serialize()`][] or [`serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize) method for that. You can apply it on a form element or input elements and which generates based on the input elements name attribute.

```
data : $('#epdate,#empname').serialize(),
// or
data : $('#epdate,#empname').serializeArray()
```

,