# Ajax Posted data not being read by $_POST in php

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to post the value of fields in a table through Ajax to process.php that will process the data.

the table:

```
<form name="items">
  <table width="90%" border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="26%">Item Name</td>
        <td width="22%">If other then give name</td>
        <td width="22%">Quantity</td>
        <td width="16%">$/Unit</td>
        <td width="14%">Total</td>
      </tr>
      <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <select name='itemname<?php echo $i;?>' id='itemname<?php echo $i;?>'>
            <option value="other">other</option>
            <?php
            $qry_item_name = "SELECT DISTINCT item_name FROM bus_name_details";
$result_item_name = mysql_query($qry_item_name);
             while($row_item_name = mysql_fetch_array($result_item_name)) {
            $option .="<option>" . $row_item_name['item_name'] . "</option>";
            echo $option;
        }
            ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="other<?php echo $i;?>" id="other<?php echo $i;?>"></td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="quan<?php echo $i;?>" id="quan<?php echo $i;?>" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="unit<?php echo $i;?>" id="unit<?php echo $i;?>" onkeyup="calculateTotal('<?php echo $i;?>')"></td>
        <td><span name="total<?php echo $i;?>" id="total<?php echo $i;?>"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <?php }?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
<span id="subm3" class="subm3" >Submit </span>
```

The Ajax:

```
    <script>
$(document).on('click', '.subm3', function() {
            var datas = {};
            for ($i = 1; $i < 2; $i++) {
                // drop down list of items
                datas["item_name"+$i]= $('#itemname'+$i+' option:selected').attr('value')
                // other name 
                datas["other"+$i]= $('input[name=other'+$i+']').val()
                // quantity
                datas["quan"+$i]= $('input[name=quan'+$i+']').val()
                // price per unit 
                datas["unit"+$i]= $('input[name=unit'+$i+']').val()

            }
            $i = $i_limit-1;
                $.ajax({
    url: 'parts/process.php?order=3&items='+$i,
   type: 'POST',
   contentType: 'application/json',
   data: JSON.stringify(datas)

});
        });
</script>
```

then the process :

```
<?php 
if ($order==3){

        $loop = $_GET[items];
        $other1= $_POST["other1"];
        echo "other1 = ".$other1;

}
?>
```

On chrome inspector i get that the data was sent like this as source :
{"item_name1":"other","other1":"Water Valve","quan1":"2","unit1":"2"}

and like this as parsed :
item_name1: "other"
other1: "Water Valve"
quan1: "2"
unit1: "2"

but the response from process.php (the one that got the values) seems to only have read the get values but not the post values :
other1 =

i am pretty much new to ajax and hope someone could help point me to where i am going wrong here. This might not even be the easiest or best way of doing what i am trying to do, but it kind of makes sense to my brain at the moment so i am taking this route. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

can you try `data:datas` insted of `data: JSON.stringify(datas)` in ajax request

ref: [how to send multiple data with $.ajax() jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078085/how-to-send-multiple-data-with-ajax-jquery)

Comment: I tried that, it also doesnt work. in chrome inspector i see :
item_name1=other&other1=water+heater&quan1=2&unit1=2

but the php is not getting the post value in 
$other1= $_POST["other1"];

Comment: try  print_r($other1); insted of echo "other1 = ".$other1; thn chk